# How to access the object's value?

Tags: javascript

There is an object and i want to access it and

show 'my name is Rudolf the raindeer'

Here is the object:

```
let obj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Rudolf',
  the: 'raindeer'
}
```

What I try in my JS:

```
   Object.entries(obj).map(value=>{

   console.log("My"+value[1]+"is"+value[2]+"the"+value[3]);

   })
```

How do i access the object right to get the value?

Comment: you can use this `let value = Object.values(obj)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join each entry by spaces, then join all the entries by spaces too:

```js
let obj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Rudolf',
  the: 'raindeer'
}

const str = Object.entries(obj)
  .map(entry => entry.join(' '))
  .join(' ');
console.log(str);
```

In newer browsers (or with a polyfill) you could `.flat`:

```js
let obj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Rudolf',
  the: 'raindeer'
}

const str = Object.entries(obj).flat().join(' ');
console.log(str);
```

Also, only use `.map` when you want to create a new array from each element of the array you're iterating over - for generic iteration, better to use `forEach`.

Comment: Join takes every element of an array and turns it into a string, with the separator passed to `join` as the separator between the elements in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution which uses a for in loop. For in loops are your friend when it comes to working with objects.

```
let obj = {my: 'name', is: 'Rudolf', the: 'raindeer'}
var sentence = '';
for(var char in obj){
    sentence += char + ' ' + obj[char] + ' ';
}
console.log(sentence)
```

In the for in loop above, char represents the key name (my, is, the) and obj[char] gives you the value for they key name ('name', 'Rudolf', 'raindeer'). Combine them together to build up the sentence.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to hard-code any words when producing the output, they want to use the property names and property values.